# Dynamic binding of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, decorator, shared-ptr

I'm trying to implement something following the decorator pattern, but I cannot seem to obtain from a shared_ptr the same run-time behaviour I can get through normal pointers.
I have a basic class ***I*** (interface) with a virtual method, then I derive from it two classes:

- class ***A*** (component) which will contain some data
- class ***B*** (decorator) which derives from ***I*** and also contains a pointer to it and will implement some additional behaviour. I have a constructor that initialises the pointer to a certain ***I*** (or derived) object.

Then I want to be able to build a ***B*** object with its pointer pointing to an ***A***, so that when I call the common methods I call the ***A*** ones not the ***I*** ones.

I can do this if I make the pointer in ***B*** in the usual way (in the code example, see the class ***B_basic*** and the object ***bb*** in the main).

But if I make this pointer like a ***shared_ptr*** to ***I*** it calls the method from ***I*** even if I build it pointing to an actual ***A*** (in code see the ***B_shared*** class and the object ***bs***)

```
class I {

   public:
      virtual void method() {cout<<"I\n";}
      virtual ~I() = default;
};

class A : public I {
   public:
      virtual void method() {cout<<"A\n";}
};

class B_shared : public I {
   public:
      shared_ptr<I> shared_pointer;
      B_shared(const I& i) : shared_pointer(make_shared<I>(i)) {}
      virtual void method() { 
         cout<<"B_shared > ";

         shared_pointer->method();
      }
};

class B_basic : public I {
   public:
      I* basic_pointer;
      B_basic(I* i) : basic_pointer(i) {}
      virtual void method() { 
         cout<<"B_basic > ";

         basic_pointer->method();
      }
};


int main() { 
   A a;
   B_shared bs(a);
   B_basic bb(&a);
   bs.method(); // B_shared > I
   bb.method(); // B_basic > A
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to follow the analogy with the raw pointer then your `B_shared` constructor should accept a `std::shared_ptr` rather than a reference to an instance.

Comment: Thanks @Galik, just saw your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is object slicing.

In the following line you make a copy of the instance `i` of type `A` to type `I`. Thus the original type `A` is sliced to base type `I`.

```
shared_pointer(make_shared<I>(i))
```

In raw pointer version `basic_pointer(i)`, you save the pointer itself, no slicing.

Comment: Thanks @liliscent, any hints on how I can avoid that happening with shared_ptr?

Comment: @Pandi If you use `shared_ptr` to manage an object's lifetime, use it from the beginning. Don't use a stack allocated instance `A a;` as in your code.

Comment: Pedantically, there is no object slicing. it is just that OP creates a `I` from `A` (expecting a `A`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Not sure whether *slicing* only refers to *assignment* pedantically. I always use *slicing* for this sort of construction.

Comment: @liliscent Yeah right! I was trying to avoid requiring the use of shared_ptr from main